# What's a simple utility function to differentiate between an old-style and a new-style python class or object

Tags: python, new-style-class

What's a simple utility function to differentiate between an old-style and a new-style python class or object?

Are the following correct/complete:

```
isNewStyle1 = lambda o: isinstance(hasattr(o, '__class__') and o.__class__ or o, type)
isNewStyle2 = lambda o: hasattr(o, '__class__') and type(o) == o.__class__ or False
```

If not, then can you provide a solution.  If so, is there a nicer way to do the check?

Using the above, I've not had any problems, but I don't have 100% confidence that it will work for all objects supplied as parameters.

Comment: `isNewStyle = lambda x: hasattr(x, "__weakref__")` Just pick a feature that new style classes have, but old style classes don't.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
class A: pass

class B(object): pass


def is_new(myclass):
    try: myclass.__class__.__class__
    except AttributeError: return False
    return True

>>> is_new(A)
False
>>> is_new(B)
True
>>> is_new(A())
False
>>> is_new(B())
True
>>> is_new(list())
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
type(my_class) is type
```

`True` for new style classes, `False` for classic classes

You can support classes with different metaclasses like this (so long as the metaclass is subclassing type)

```
issublass(type(myclass), type)
```

Comment: That only covers classes, I'm trying to account for any object, for example type(list()) is list, so that would fail your test.

Comment: Then my_class = type(list()).  Just do that test for the type of any arbitrary object.

Comment: @Cyrus, Magically trying to support instances and classes is a bad idea. Consider that a class _is_ an _instance_ of `type` (usually).